# Using Scala IDE with MacOS

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I'm new in Scala and I'm following a course on Linkedin Learning. I'm trying to configure Eclipse to work with the Scala IDE or to use the standalone Scala IDE based on Eclipse Oxygen.
I'm using MacOS Big Sur 11.1 and I know that there is some issue with that.
The problem is that I can use the standalone Scala IDE that I download from http://scala-ide.org/ because, when I run it, I have these errors when I try to import a project:
[ScalaIDEerror1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjwvO.png) [ScalaIDEerror2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC2A1.png)

Also, if I download Eclipse plugin for Scala (with Eclipse 2021-03(4.19.0)) I got the following errors.
[EclipseError1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYeU2.png) [EclipseError2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjRdb.png)
I've tried to google about it but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: As far as I know, the Eclipse Scala IDE is no longer maintained since a few years. I would suggest https://scalameta.org/metals/ or IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I didn't know scalameta, I'm trying with IntelliJ IDEA at the moment, but I need to understand if I can follow the examples in the course, since there they use Eclipse Scala IDE.

Comment: You should tell them to update their courses. But hopefully it shouldn't make much difference which IDE you're using.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Still annoying though that it's not working.